# Installation failing on Latitude D620

Tags: boot, system-installation, usb, dell

I'm trying to install 14.04.3 on a Dell Latitude D620 and am failing.

The procedure I used was to download the file `ubuntu-14.04.3-desktop-i386.iso` to both my Thinkpad running Debian 8 and, alternatively, to the target Dell, which is running Windows 7. I attempted to make bootable USB drive on the Debian box by running as root the command `dd if=/path/to/ubuntu-14.04.3-desktop-i386.iso of=/dev/sdb'.

This did create a bootable drive that started the Ubuntu installer on the Dell.  There was an Ubuntu splash screen and the color-changing dots, after which the installation failed in two different ways.  The first way was that the screen showed a black-and-white, elongated checker-board pattern and drive activity seemed to cease.  No questions were ever asked by the install program.

Thinking that the ISO was specific to the Thinkpad, I downloaded the same file on the Dell and wrote it to the pendrive using the site and EXE program Universal USB Installer.  This failed in a screen that was poorly rendered in the top half with text "Username", "Password", and "Remember me" and static on the bottom half.

I've searched for any forum posts with the keywords "latitude d620" and "failed install" and all I find are a few posts about wifi driver issues.  There seems to be very little failure of the Ubuntu distribution to install, so I'm asking for help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to simply give the install-from-USB-key more time--a lot of time.  When I left for Mardi Gras the funky display was present.  When I returned several hours later, the laptop was running from the USB key with an Ubuntu desktop displayed, including a link icon titled "Install Ubuntu".  Thanks for the help!